# Changing a heaviside function into a one line function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$h(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}1,\, \pi\leq t<2\pi\\
       0,\, 0\leq t<\pi\text{ and }t\geq2\pi\end{array}\right.$$

I need to change $h(t)$ into a one line function.

I believe it to be $h(t)=u_{\pi}(t) - u_{2\pi} (t)$

The part that is throwing me is the $t \geq 2\pi$. Normally these are $t \geq 0$.

I really wish there was an equation editor on here....

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to consider it as three separate parts:
$$h(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}   0,\, 0\leq t<\pi \\ 
1,\, \pi\leq t<2\pi\\
0, t\geq2\pi \end{array}\right.$$

The most systematic way I find to turn these into heaviside functions is to start with the top-most, then add heaviside times the function on the next step minus that of the previous step:
$$h(t)=0+u_\pi(t)\cdot(1-0)+u_{2\pi}(t)\cdot(0-1)\\
=u_\pi-u_{2\pi},$$
As you said.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't sure if we could "rearrange" these functions. I really appreciate you fully showing the steps. This helps me tremendously!